# why am i receiving this python error when importing data from a csv file?

Tags: python, type-conversion

I am trying to import data from a csv file and convert the data to an int. but i am receiving this error:

```
year = int(i[0])
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I also get this error for converting month and day to an int

```
with open('tide.csv', 'w') as tides_data:
tides = csv.writer(tides_data, delimiter=' ',
                   quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
with open('test_csv.csv', 'r') as data_file:
    data = csv.reader(data_file, delimiter=',')
    for i in data:
        year = 2018 #the program has a bug here. please change so it can bring in the year from the csv file
        month = int(i[1])
        day = int(i[2])
        time = str(i[3])
```

[image: here is the csv file]

Comment: What is the value of `i[0]` that causes the error?

Comment: the value is 2018

Comment: How do you know? Did you `print` it?

Comment: yes i printed it

Comment: Did you print it _just before_ attempting to convert to `int`? In the very same program?

Comment: yes. i also did print type(year) and it said it was a string which was expected. then i did year = int(year) and then i did print type(year) again and it said int and then i got the same error

Comment: What does `year` have to do with it? Did you `print(i[0])`?

Comment: yes, and this is the result: 2018
<type 'str'>

Comment: Please include a portion of the CSV file in your question (not a screenshot but the real text).

Comment: 2018 8 6 16:15 -84.05111884 9.9389431 1195.302
2018 8 6 16:20 -84.05111884 9.9389431 1195.302

thats the first few lines. the 2018 is copied on each line

Comment: Your delimiter is not a comma but a TAB, And you said it was a comma: `csv.reader(data_file, delimiter=',')`.

Comment: sorry, i copied the data from the excel file. it is comma delimited:

2018,8,6,16:15,-84.05111884,9.9389431,1195.302,,,,
2018,8,6,16:20,-84.05111884,9.9389431,1195.302,,,,

this is from notepad

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error with the dataset that you provided. Perhaps there is an empty row at the end of the file?

Comment: yes! it seems like there was an empty row! thank you for the help